# Meaning of the term $x_n$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I've started the lesson an Newton's method, and am Looking at this formula, 
$$x_{n+1} = x_n - \dfrac{f(x_n)}{f'(x_n)}$$

I know when the numbers are to the top like in $x^2$, what that is, but what does it mean when they are subscripted, to the bottom like in the Newton's method formula?

Comment: Look up the term "Sequences" on Google.

Comment: Suppose you have a value and you need a variable.  So you label it x.  Then you need another.  You label it y.  Then you need several more, maybe you need an infinite number more.  What do you label this long sequence of values?  You could label them $x_0, x_1,x_2... $.  The subscript is simply a way of indexing a sequence of values giving them indexed variables.  In this case the values are recursively defined.  The n-th var

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A subscript, as $x_n$, often means the n-th term in a sequence.The sequence may be finite or infinite and it is not necessary to start at $n=1$ nor at $n=0$.For example "let p_n be the n-th prime " (in increasing order,which in this case is usually not stated but assumed) means that (assuming we start the count at $n=1$) $p_1=2,p_2=3,p_3=5,p_4=7$,etc. In calculus we are almost always talking about  sequences, and it often more readable to use subscripts.For example if we have a sequence of FUNCTIONS we could write them as $f(1),f(2),...$,etc but then when $x$  belongs to the domain of the function $f(1)$ then the value of this function at the point $x$ is $f(1)(x)$ because the 4 consecutive keystrokes "$f(1)$" comprise the name of the function.It is easier to read if we write $f_1,f_2,...$ and then write $f_1(x)$ for the value of $f_1$ at $x$. Subscripts are not limited to natural numbers, and a subscript may have its own subscript...Example :Theorem: For each real number $x$ let $V_x$ be an open interval containing $x$. Then there exists an infinite sequence $x_1,x_2,x_3,...$ of real numbers such that for every real $x$, there exists at least one $n$ for which $x\in V_{x_n}$.

Answer (score 1):

Newton's method seeks to find an approximate solution to the equation "$f(x)=0$" (i.e. a root of $f$).

$x_0$ is an initial "guess" at a solution. Feeding this into your equation: $x_1 = x_0 - f(x_0)/f'(x_0)$ gives a better approximate solution.

Feeding $x_1$ into the equation again: $x_2=x_1-f(x_1)/f'(x_1)$ gives an even better approximate solution.

$x_n$ is the $n$-th attempt (i.e. iteration) at finding a solution.